# How to write an object into a text file in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, text-files

I have this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

z = requests.get("http://www.reuters.com/article/us-myanmar-usa-sanctions-idUSKCN0Y92RK/")

url2 = 'http://www.reuters.com/article/us-myanmar-usa-sanctions-idUSKCN0Y92RK'
response2 = requests.get(url2)

soup2 = BeautifulSoup(response2.content, "html.parser")
for sentence in soup2.select("#articleText p"):
    block_text = sentence.get_text()
    print(block_text)

f = open("article.text" , "w")
f.write(block_text)
```

that is supposed to take the data from block_text and put it into a text file. Unfortunately, my text file only contains the last sentence of the block_text object. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unfortunately, my text file only contains the last sentence of the block_text object.

Of course, that's because you write to the file only after the loop using the *last `block_text` value*.

Instead, you can do:

```
with open("article.text" , "w") as f:
    for sentence in soup2.select("#articleText p"):
        block_text = sentence.get_text()
        f.write(block_text)
```